# Playing audio from URL give me this log error and stuck .(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, stream, 3g

I had audio playing through URL, it is working fine using Wifi network but when i change to 3G or Data, it would give this error and it stuck at loading.

```
>  CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sync = syna;
}
```

> <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iOS 11 ? 
I encountered the exact debug message on iOS 11.

Comment: Yes, I am using iOS 11.